# Python's Popen cleanup

Tags: python, popen, resource-cleanup

I wanted to use a python equivalent to piping some shell commands in perl.  Something like the python version of open(PIPE, "command |").

I go to the subprocess module and try this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen("zgrep thingiwant largefile", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

This works for reading the output the same way I would in perl, but it doesn't clean itself up.  When I exit the interpreter, I get

```
grep: writing output: Broken pipe
```

spewed all over stderr a few million times.  I guess I had naively hoped all this would be taken care of for me, but that's not true.  Calling terminate or kill on p doesn't seem to help.  Look at the process table, I see that this kills the /bin/sh process, but leaves the child gzip in place to complain about the broken pipe.

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: Are you exiting the interpreter before your subprocess `p` has finished?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue is that the `pipe` is full. The subprocess stops, waiting for the pipe to empty out, but then your process (the Python interpreter) quits, breaking its end of the pipe (hence the error message).

`p.wait()` will not help you:

> **Warning** This will deadlock if the child process generates enough output to a stdout or stderr pipe such that it blocks waiting for the OS pipe buffer to accept more data. Use `communicate()` to avoid that.
>
> http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait

`p.communicate()` will not help you:

> **Note** The data read is buffered in memory, so do not use this method if the data size is large or unlimited.
>
> http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate

`p.stdout.read(num_bytes)` will not help you:

> **Warning** Use `communicate()` rather than `.stdin.write`, `.stdout.read` or `.stderr.read` to avoid deadlocks due to any of the other OS pipe buffers filling up and blocking the child process.
>
> http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stdout

The moral of the story is, for large output, `subprocess.PIPE` will doom you to certain failure if your program is trying to read the data (it seems to me that you should be able to put `p.stdout.read(bytes)` into a `while p.returncode is None:` loop, but the above warning suggests that this could deadlock).

The docs suggest replacing a shell pipe with this:

```
p1 = Popen(["zgrep", "thingiwant", "largefile"], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["processreceivingdata"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
output = p2.communicate()[0]
```

Notice that `p2` is taking its standard input directly from `p1`. This *should* avoid deadlocks, but given the contradictory warnings above, *who knows*.

Anyway, if that last part doesn't work for you (it *should*, though), you could try creating a temporary file, writing all data from the first call to that, and then using the temporary file as input to the next process.

Answer (score 3):

After you open the pipe, you can work with the command output: `p.stdout`:

```
for line in p.stdout:
    # do stuff
p.stdout.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

How did you executed this process?

Proper way is to use

```
p.communicate()
```

See docs for more details.

Comment: This occurs even if I never communicate with the process.  Just creating the object p and then exiting the interpreter causes this problem.

Comment: Yes, if I recall correctly, Popen executes the command. `communicate()` then waits until the process has ended, buffers are flushed etc. etc.

Also see `check_call()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `wait` for the process to finish:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen("cat /mach_kernel", shell=True)
p.wait()
```

Alternatively, you can capture the program's standard output (as you have), and perhaps its standard error, and then call `communicate`:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen("cat /mach_kernel", shell=True,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```