# Python grep and pipe through Popen

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to grep from a directory and limit the search to the first 100 results. The following code  keeps yielding

```
[..]
grep: writing output: Broken pipe
grep: writing output: Broken pipe
grep: writing output: Broken pipe
grep: writing output: Broken pipe
[..]
```

The code:

```
p_grep = Popen(['/bin/bash', '-c', 'grep -F  "asdasdasd" data/*'], stdout = PIPE)
p_head = Popen(['head', '-100'], stdin = p_grep.stdout, stdout = PIPE)
output = p_head.communicate()[0]
```

How to fix it?

Comment: try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595602/pythons-popen-cleanup

Comment: @xkrz, isn't the suggested solution there exactly what he's doing?

Comment: Do you need to execute grep or is this only an example? Otherwise, grep has a --max-count option you can use instead of piping the whole output through.

Comment: max-count limits the number of rows read in a file, i need to limit the number of searches from all files.

Comment: @RobWouters, you are right, the example given at the end is exactly what pistcchio doing. My apology for not reading the other post to the end.

Answer (score 1):

Actually in this case you can do:

```
output = check_output(['/bin/bash', '-c', 'grep -F  "asdasdasd" data/* | head -100'])
```

Comment: the problem with this is that, i don't know why, it executes ALL the grepping and then it pipes throu head, so, while in the shell it only takes some seconds, it takes much longer in python

Comment: @pistacchio, can you try passing `--line-buffered` to `grep` and see if that changes anything?

Comment: I can't think of any reasons why there would be a difference. Are you absolutely certain you are comparing the exact same commands? The only other thing is maybe pass `bufsize=1` to check_output.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Popen documentation on writing pipes](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline) you should make sure to close the `stdout` on the piped processes (in this case `p_grep`) so that they are able to receive a `SIGPIPE` from the piped-to processes (in this case `p_head`).

Furthermore, according to [this post](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/ucgi/~cjwatson/blosxom/2009-07-02-python-sigpipe.html), it's important to provide a setup function to each subprocess so that Python's handling of `SIGPIPE` is restored to its default behavior.

So the code becomes:

```
def preexec_fn():
    import signal
    signal.signal(signal.SIGPIPE, signal.SIG_DFL)

p_grep = Popen(['/bin/bash', '-c', 'grep -F  "asdasdasd" data/*'], stdout=PIPE, preexec_fn=preexec_fn)
p_head = Popen(['head', '-100'], stdin=p_grep.stdout, stdout=PIPE, preexec_fn=preexec_fn)
p_grep.stdout.close()
output = p_head.communicate()[0]
```

That should cause the `grep` process to terminate once `head` completes.