# Popen in main and subprocess

Tags: python

the following code (in the main thread) works well, I grep some files and the search *until* the first 100 results are found (writing the results to a file), then exit:

```
    command = 'grep -F "%s" %s*.txt' % (search_string, DATA_PATH)

    p = Popen(['/bin/bash', '-c', command], stdout = PIPE)
    f = open(output_file, 'w+')
    num_lines = MAX_RESULTS
    while True:  
        line = p.stdout.readline()
        print num_lines
        if line != '':
            f.write(line)
        num_lines = num_lines - 1
        if num_lines == 0:
            break
        else:
            break
```

The very same code used into a Process subclass, always returns `grep: writing output: Broken pipe` in the console:

```
    class Search(Process):
        def __init__(self, search_id, search_string):
            self.search_id = search_id
            self.search_string = search_string  
            self.grepped = ''
            Process.__init__(self)

        def run(self):
            output_file = TMP_PATH + self.search_id

            # flag if no regex chars
            flag = '-F' if re.match(r"^[a-zA-Z0\ ]*$", self.search_string) else '-P'    

            command = 'grep %s "%s" %s*.txt' % (flag, self.search_string, DATA_PATH)

            p = Popen(['/bin/bash', '-c', command], stdout = PIPE)
            f = open(output_file, 'w+')
            num_lines = MAX_RESULTS
            while True:  
                line = p.stdout.readline()
                print num_lines
                if line != '':
                    f.write(line)
                num_lines = num_lines - 1
                if num_lines == 0:
                    break
                else:
                    break
```

How come? How to fix this?

Comment: Why are you using grep while Python has very solid [regex](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) solutions itself?

Comment: because i have to search through 1.5+ Gb of data and the speed of grep is not matchable by python.

Comment: Looks like the same question as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595602/pythons-popen-cleanup When I have had problems with capturing command output, I've increased the size of the buffer: `p = Popen(['/bin/bash', '-c', command], stdout = PIPE, bufsize=256 * 1024 * 1024)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the error message like this:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import subprocess
import shlex

def worker():
    proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('''
        /bin/bash -c "grep -P 'foo' /tmp/test.txt"
        '''), stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
    line = proc.stdout.readline()
    print(line)
    # proc.terminate()   # This fixes the problem

if __name__=='__main__':
    N = 6000
    with open('/tmp/test.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write('bar foo\n'*N)   # <--- Increasing this number causes grep: writing output: Broken pipe
    p = mp.Process(target = worker)
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

If the above code does not produce the error for you, increase the size of the file /tmp/test.txt by increasing `N`. (Conversely, you can hide the fact that there is a bug in the code by reducing `N`.)

If the worker process ends before the grep subprocess, then the grep gets a SIGPIPE telling it that its stdout has been closed. `grep` responds by printing

```
grep: writing output: Broken pipe
```

to stderr, once for every line it is still processing.

The fix is to terminate the process with `proc.terminate()` before `worker` ends.

Comment: why would my process end before grep if i have an infinite while loop reading from grep itself?

Comment: Your while loop is `break`ing after one iteration.